# Multiple JSpinners Initialized differently

Tags: java, swing, editor, number-formatting, jspinner

I have 2 JSpinners in my application , I  set the model , editor , number format for both of them. However when I run the application the second one doesn't show the fractional part 
initially. This Looks like focusing issue.

So first one intialized 0.0 but second one is initialized as 0; I want second one the same with first. Do I miss step here ? Here is my code below.

[image]

Here is My Code

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private final JSpinner.NumberEditor editor;
    DecimalFormat format , format2 ; 
    private final JSpinner.NumberEditor editor1;

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();

        SpinnerNumberModel model1 = new SpinnerNumberModel(0.0,-1000.0 ,1000.0,0.1); 
        this.jSpinner1.setModel(model1);
        editor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(this.jSpinner1);
        this.jSpinner1.setEditor(editor);
        format = editor.getFormat(); 
        format.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);

        SpinnerNumberModel model2 = new SpinnerNumberModel(0.0,-1000.0 ,1000.0,0.1); 
        this.jSpinner2.setModel(model2);
        editor1 = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(this.jSpinner2);
        this.jSpinner2.setEditor(editor1);
        format2 = editor1.getFormat(); 
        format2.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);


    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jSpinner1 = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
        jSpinner2 = new javax.swing.JSpinner();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                formMouseMoved(evt);
            }
        });

        jSpinner1.setFocusable(false);
        jSpinner1.setOpaque(false);
        jSpinner1.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);

        jSpinner2.setFocusable(false);
        jSpinner2.setOpaque(false);
        jSpinner2.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jSpinner2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 245, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jSpinner1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 245, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(41, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                .addComponent(jSpinner1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jSpinner2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(31, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void formMouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                               

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JSpinner jSpinner1;
    private javax.swing.JSpinner jSpinner2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Please provide a full runnable example. Probably when you do it, you will find the answer by yourself.

Comment: see i think the first one is focused thats why , how to set both focused initiall or other solution , i have updated my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set format directly to the text field of the editors

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.InternationalFormatter;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
//    private final JSpinner.NumberEditor editor;
    DecimalFormat format , format2 ;
//    private final JSpinner.NumberEditor editor1;

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();

        SpinnerNumberModel model1 = new SpinnerNumberModel(0.0,-1000.0 ,1000.0,0.1);
        this.jSpinner1.setModel(model1);

        SpinnerNumberModel model2 = new SpinnerNumberModel(0.0,-1000.0 ,1000.0,0.1);
        this.jSpinner2.setModel(model2);

        (((JSpinner.NumberEditor)this.jSpinner1.getEditor()).getTextField()).setFormatterFactory(new JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatterFactory() {
            @Override
            public JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter getFormatter(JFormattedTextField tf) {
                NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
                format.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
                InternationalFormatter formatter = new InternationalFormatter(format);
                formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
                formatter.setMinimum(-1000.0);
                formatter.setMaximum(1000.00);
                return formatter;
            }
        });
        (((JSpinner.NumberEditor)this.jSpinner2.getEditor()).getTextField()).setFormatterFactory(new JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatterFactory() {
            @Override
            public JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter getFormatter(JFormattedTextField tf) {
                NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
                format.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
                InternationalFormatter formatter = new InternationalFormatter(format);
                formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
                formatter.setMinimum(-1000.0);
                formatter.setMaximum(1000.00);
                return formatter;
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jSpinner1 = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
        jSpinner2 = new javax.swing.JSpinner();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                formMouseMoved(evt);
            }
        });

        jSpinner1.setFocusable(false);
        jSpinner1.setOpaque(false);
        jSpinner1.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);

        jSpinner2.setFocusable(false);
        jSpinner2.setOpaque(false);
        jSpinner2.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                        .addComponent(jSpinner2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 245, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(jSpinner1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 245, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addContainerGap(41, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                                .addComponent(jSpinner1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jSpinner2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addContainerGap(31, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void formMouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JSpinner jSpinner1;
    private javax.swing.JSpinner jSpinner2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , it is working fine now  ,I also wonder the issue  becuase I think the issue with focusing thing , how remove focus on these spinners  and set value like that do you have answer for that as well ?

Comment: Looks like you change format but the format is used after some lag. Focus kind of "forces" the refreshing and content is repainted.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use a [JSpinner.NumberEditor(JSpinner spinner, String decimalFormatPattern)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.NumberEditor.html#NumberEditor-javax.swing.JSpinner-java.lang.String-):

```
editor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(this.jSpinner1, "0.0");
```